# c++: Mutually referenced structs in multi-file c++ project

Tags: c++, oop

Drafting a project, I found it easiest to create mutually referenced structs in the `main.cpp` file as follows:

```
struct component;
struct vertex{
     component * parent;
     ...;
}
struct component{
     vector<vertex *> vertices;
     ...;
}
```

Before I start coding up the final version of these structs as classes in a header file, is this the accepted way to do this?

Or is there a way one is "supposed" to create mutually referencing structs/classes?

Comment: Put them in a header rather than a C++ file.  Make your header file self-contained.  E.g., since you are using `vector`, you will have a `#include <vector>` in your header.  However, do *NOT* have a `using namespace std;` -- use fully qualified (e.g., `std::vector< ... >` instead.

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps haha, yes have encountered ***that*** particular problem...thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfectly acceptable, and it is called "Forward Declaration." You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

Comment: will accept when timer runs out.